# Convert for-loop into mathematical expression

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I'm facing a simple problem actually:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < noutput_items; i++){
    out[i] = in[i] * in[i];
  }
```

When I want to formalize this as a math expression, how do I issue the limits?

$$\sum_{i=0}^{noutput\_items} in_i$$ was my initial guess, but of course it's not a sum. It's a while ago when I last checked how sequences can be expressed with integrals or as sums... Could somebody help me to refresh my memory :)

Best,
Marius

Comment: It is extremely unclear what are $\operatorname{in}[i], \operatorname{out}[i]$ and I assume that nooutput_items is a predefined constant, or it is not clear what purpose does the loop serve? I would advise that you post some more parts of the code. This snippet, as it stands is extremely unhelpful!

Comment: I'd write something like $\operatorname{out} = \operatorname{in}^2$.

Comment: Or $\forall i \in \{0, 1, \ldots, noutput\\_ items-1\}.\ out_i = in_i^2$.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to use a "formal" and "succint" mathematical expression, you can use the [Hadamard Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29), where the Hadamard product of two matrices is got by mutiplying the corresponding entries.

So if the input is treated as a vector: $\text{inp}$, then the output vector $\text{out}$ is given by

$$ \text{out} = \text{inp} \circ \text{inp}$$

where $\circ$ is the Hadamard product.

Note that you can treat a vector as a $1\times n$ matrix.

Of course, this will probably force your readers to try and figure out what a Hadamard product is, and you might as well just write

$$ \text{out}[i] = \text{inp}[i]^2 \quad \forall i \in \{0, 1, \dots , n-1\} $$

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways. Here's a memory-*unaware* approach:

Let $n = $ `noutput_items`. Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ diagonal matrix, representing `in[]`. That is, the entry $A_{i,i} = $ `in[i-1]`. Then the matrix $B = AA$ is a diagonal matrix where `out[i-1]` $ = B_{i,i}.$